# Query on Modem Manager support for Sierra Wireless 5G module (EM9191)

Tags: modem

I am trying to use modem manager for sierra wireless 5G module (EM9191). The lsusb detected the module but mmcli -L could detect the module. 4G module worked fine. Do we have a fix for this?